# How can I make players spawn with a sword after dying?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a bedwars map in Minecraft.

In real bedwars, when a player dies, they keep only their sword.

How can I make it so that players spawn with a wooden sword?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2683916-give-player-an-item-on-respawn?comment=10) work for you?

Comment: no it is blocked for me

Comment: What do you mean by "it's blocked for me?" Is it that you are unable to access the page? Either way, I've posted the linked page as an answer, if you've already read it and it doesn't work, just wait for a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a death Counter first

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
```

I recommend functions but you can use a repeat command block and a chain command block, too

```
/execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..}] run give @s minecraft:iron_sword
/execute as @a[scores={deaths=1..}] run scoreboard players reset @s deaths
```

Comment: You can simplify the last command by using  `scoreboard players reset @a[scores={deaths=1..}] deaths` instead...

Answer (score 1):

Use a scoreboard objective that tracks the time since the player last died.

```
/scoreboard players add deathTime time_since_death
```

Then run, in a repeating command block:

```
/give @a[scores={deathTime=1}] wooden_sword
```